# Using an F# portable library with HTML5/Javascript on Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, f#, windows-phone-8

sorry if this has already been answered but the other posts on this are out of date.

I want to build a Windows 8 app in HTML5 and JavaScript that uses an F# portable library project to do the computational heavy lifting. Is this allowed? When I tried to add a reference to my F# project from the JS project VS2012 gave me an error but then let me add it anyway, will this blow up in my face later? I also want to make a Windows Phone 8 version

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the current F# compiler cannot create a WINMD component (mentioned by Denis) so you won't be able to call F# code directly from JavaScript. It might be possible (but I'm not sure!) to create an F# library as a portable library and reference it from a C# project compiled as WINMD component and then reference *that* from JavaScript. This adds an additional step, so it might be a bit inconvenient.

Please submit this as a feedback on the [Visual Studio UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/30935-languages-f-). It is more likely to be added if more people vote clearly say that this is an important scenario for them!

Alternatively, as mentioned by Ramon, there are tools that translate F# to JavaScript and would allow you to run your F# code as JavaScript (and call it directly from JS):

- [WebSharper](http://www.websharper.com/home) is a commercial, supported product with an open-source release under the AGPL license.
- [FunScript](https://github.com/ZachBray/FunScript) is a recent open-source community effort that is available under Apache 2.0

I only have experience with FunScript (which works pretty well and has some nice features), but WebSharper has been around for longer, so I suppose it is more solid. It also adds more sophisticated GUI framework based on *formlets* (and similar patterns) while FunScript simply provides type-safe access to JQuery via a type provider that imports TypeScript definitions.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript metro apps can not call .net libraries directly. To make it possible for javascript to call your F# library you should turn it into windows runtime component (winmd). Now, I am not 100% sure if it is possible to make winmd using F#, since officially  microsoft only supports c# and VB. On WP8 side javascript can not call .net or winmd libraries directly, so you would have to bridge js and .net manually.